# ImportError: Python version mismatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, face-recognition

I wrote a simple script using `face_recognition` python library. But when I tried to execute the script I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face.py", line 1, in <module>
    import face_recognition
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/face_recognition/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 4, in <module>
    import dlib
ImportError: Python version mismatch: module was compiled for version 3.8, while the interpreter is running version 3.7.
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Create a new virtual env with python 3.8

Comment: @Sushanth - Can you explain the steps and post it as an answer.? Let me try.  Meanwhile, I am using ubuntu

Comment: [`install Python 3.8 in ubuntu`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246153/1102394)

Comment: or maybe install an older version https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/#history by using pip install face-recognition==1.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Install Python 3.8, this would solve the problem